# Sending WETHs instead of MATIC Tokens in Function Calls on Polygon Network

Tags: solidity, polygon, layer-2

I had initially developed a Smart Contract for the Ethereum Blockchain. Within my Dapp, I would have called a mint function found in my Smart Contract using the function below. This function would have transferred by default Ethers to my Smart Contract. I have now decided to deploy my Smart Contract on the Polygon Network instead. However, by using the function below, it would then now transfer MATIC tokens and no longer ETHs upon calling it. How can I change this code so that it now sends WETHs instead of MATIC tokens when calling the function on the Polygon Network?

```
contract.methods.mint(this.account, NFT).send({
   from: this.account,
   value: web3.utils.toWei(price, 'ether')
})
```

Thank you. J

Comment: you cannot send ETH using value, ETH on MATIC is an ERC20 token, so it means you need to changes your smart contract to allow payment using ERC20 methods

Comment: Hi @AdamBoudjemaa In order to simplify my code (and usability for users), I have decided to have users use MATIC tokens instead of WETHs in my Dapp, which will now be deployed on Polygon. From my initial testing, it appears that I can use all the functionality of my Smart Contract/Dapp that I had initially developed for Ethereum exactly as is, without proceeding to any modifications. That is, every time that a user would have used/sent ETHs, it will now use/send MATIC Tokens instead. Is this a correct assumption or are there still anything that I would need to modify or be aware of? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly like ETH, except that the blockchain where you run your smart contract will use a different native coin, instead of ETH it will be MATIC.

ETH, BNB, MATIC, FTM, AVAX are just names, but from the EVM perspective, it is considered as ETH even if it's not Ether. since there are all forks of Ethereum (EVM), for the EVM itself there is no concept of MATIC or BNB or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation @AdamBoudjemaa